# How to add columns using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have df as below and want to add additional column using Scala

```
Id Name
1  ab
2  BC
1  Cd
2  mf
3  Hh
```

Expected output should be below

```
Id name repeatedcount
1  ab      2
2  BC      2
1  Cd      2
2  mf      2
3  Hh      3
```

I'm using `DF.groupBy($"id").count.show()` but I'm getting different output.

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Can you explain how did you obtain the values under `repeatedcount`? If you group by `id`, why is it 3 for `id = 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val grouped = df.groupBy($"id").count

val res = df.join(grouped,Seq("id"))
            .withColumnRenamed("count","repeatedcount")
```

Group By will give count of each id's. Join that with original dataframe to get count against each id.